# Child transform's position not updated as parent moves

Tags: unity, c#

I have a parent game object `Object1`. It has a child, which is simply an empty game object called `ReferencePoint`. `ReferencePoint` can be any arbitrary point on `Object1` itself.

I have another game object `Object2`. It has a public field called `RotationReference`, of type `Transform`. In the inspector, the `ReferencePoint` on `Object1` is assigned to the `RotationReference` field on  `Object2`.

As `Object1` moves, I expect `ReferencePoint` to change its position as well. `Object2` is supposed to change its rotation to face its `RotationReference` -- in this case, the `ReferencePoint` on `Object1`:

```
public override void Rotate()
{
    Vector3 relativeRotationReferencePosition =
        this.RotationReference.position - this.transform.position;

    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativeRotationReferencePosition);
}
```

However, I noticed that `Object2` is not rotating at all, even when `Object1` is moving. When I step through the call stack multiple times, I discover that `this.RotationReference.position` always has the same value, even though `Object1` is moving.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what language are you using

Comment: This might sound silly, but I get the feeling you've done a mistake somewhere and the empty objects do not move, when you think they are. Have you done anything to ensure that they move as expected? Like debugging it's position, or even just giving them a mesh so that you can see them while the game is running ?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that the position itself does not change, probably it is due to some mistake in assigning a value to rotationReference. Check that you do not change its value anywhere in the code. And it is "RotationReference = ReferencePoint" not the other way round and so on.

Also I don't see why you need referencePoint on object1 and not just use Object1 itself as the target. But maybe I just don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The value is not mutated anywhere in code. The reason for using a referencePoint is complicated; but, long story short: The existing models that I have to work with (created in and imported from an external program) require some hacks for them to behave properly in the scene.